# Como modificar mi filtro de busqueda en mi ecommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, woocommerce

Tengo mi pagina de e-commerce que filtra los productos por el nombre, y yo quiero filtrar tambien por etiqueta de producto y no puedo entender como hacerlo.

He pensado en una consulta SQL en phpmyadmin, pero no puedo encontrar cual es la tabla donde estan los productos.

Quiero hacerlo sin utilizar plugins.

Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que "etiqueta de producto" esta en una tabla externa.
Entonces tienes que utilizar inner join para realizar consultas de tablas relacionadas.

Asi un ejemplo:

```
select pro.nombreproducto from productos as pro inner join "tabla etiqueta" as eti on eti.id_etiqueta = pro.id_etiqueta where eti.nombre_etiquita like concat('','%','NombreEtiqueta','%');
```

Esto es un ejemplo, pero si quieres mas ayuda, debes ser mas especifico, busca tus tablas y pasa foto.